Deprecation Warning with groupby.apply - problem using with lambda and group
I have a python function that checks for the number of unique values of 'Name' for each unique value of 'DecId'. If there is more than one 'Name' for a 'DecId', 'Name' is appended to 'DecId' so there is only one unique combination of each 'Name' and 'DecId'. Below is my example code:
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame creation

data = {

   'DecId': ['D1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D2', 'D3', 'D3'],

   'Name': ['JohnDoe1', 'JaneDoe2', 'AliceSmith', 'NON EEA', 'BobBrown', 'BobBrown'],

   'OtherColumn': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

}

 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 

# Function to process each group and modify DecID if necessary due to multiple Names

def mod_dec_ids_name(group):

    if len(group['Name'].unique()) > 1:

        #combine any instances of NON EEA into NON_EEA

        group['Name'] = group['Name'].str.replace('NON EEA', 'NON_EEA', regex=False)

        # If there are multiple unique Names, modify DecId

        group['DecId'] = group['DecId'] + '_' + group['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])

    return group

 

# Group by DecID and apply the processing function to check Names

df2 = df.groupby('DecId').apply(lambda group: mod_dec_ids_name(group)).reset_index(drop=True)

 

print(df2)

This gives me the desired output like this:
           DecId        Name  OtherColumn

0    D1_JohnDoe1    JohnDoe1           10

1    D1_JaneDoe2    JaneDoe2           20

2  D2_AliceSmith  AliceSmith           30

3     D2_NON_EEA     NON_EEA           40

4             D3    BobBrown           50

5             D3    BobBrown           60

However I get this warning:
:1: DeprecationWarning: DataFrameGroupBy.apply operated on the grouping columns. This behavior is deprecated, and in a future version of pandas the grouping columns will be excluded from the operation. Either pass include_groups=False to exclude the groupings or explicitly select the grouping columns after groupby to silence this warning.
I understand this is because I'm using pandas 2.2 and this function is being changed for pandas 3. I have tried fixing this using advice from a previous post (Deprecation Warning with groupby.apply) but when I add include_groups=False to my code it breaks!
df2 = df.groupby('DecId').apply(lambda group: mod_dec_ids_name(group), include_groups=False).reset_index(drop=True)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc

    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "index.pyx", line 167, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "index.pyx", line 196, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7081, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7089, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'DecId'

 

 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1819, in apply

    return self._python_apply_general(f, self._obj_with_exclusions)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1885, in _python_apply_general

    values, mutated = self._grouper.apply_groupwise(f, data, self.axis)

    res = f(group)

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>

  File "<stdin>", line 4, in mod_dec_ids_name

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4102, in __getitem__

    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3812, in get_loc

    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'DecId'

I feel like I'm missing something in terms of how to add the include_groups=False term. Any advice on how I can modify this code not to give me a warning would be greatly appreciated.

You can fix warning by pass all columns names after groupby, also is possible simplify solution removing lambda:
df2 = (df.groupby('DecId')[df.columns.tolist()]
         .apply(mod_dec_ids_name)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print(df2)
           DecId        Name  OtherColumn
0    D1_JohnDoe1    JohnDoe1           10
1    D1_JaneDoe2    JaneDoe2           20
2  D2_AliceSmith  AliceSmith           30
3     D2_NON_EEA     NON_EEA           40
4             D3    BobBrown           50
5             D3    BobBrown           60

Also is possible use parameter group_keys=False in groupby for avoid MultiIndex, so .reset_index(drop=True) should be removed:
df2 = df.groupby('DecId', group_keys=False)[df.columns.tolist()].apply(mod_dec_ids_name)
print(df2)
           DecId        Name  OtherColumn
0    D1_JohnDoe1    JohnDoe1           10
1    D1_JaneDoe2    JaneDoe2           20
2  D2_AliceSmith  AliceSmith           30
3     D2_NON_EEA     NON_EEA           40
4             D3    BobBrown           50
5             D3    BobBrown           60


I think the problem arises when the group key is included in the column to which the apply function is applied. Using the by of groupby as a grouper solves it.
use following code:
df2 = (df.groupby(df['DecId'].rename(None))
         .apply(lambda group: mod_dec_ids_name(group), include_groups=False)
         .reset_index(drop=True)
)

df2:
           DecId        Name  OtherColumn
0    D1_JohnDoe1    JohnDoe1           10
1    D1_JaneDoe2    JaneDoe2           20
2  D2_AliceSmith  AliceSmith           30
3     D2_NON_EEA     NON_EEA           40
4             D3    BobBrown           50
5             D3    BobBrown           60

